Sick PicoScan 150 - Start Multiple Nodes
I would like to use 2 Sick PicoScan150 in Ros2 Humble.
My IpAddresses are as follows configured on the sick scanner:
Scanner1 : 192.168.0.101 (host ip), ros2 ip : 192.168.0.100 (udp receiver ip) udp port 4112
Scanner2 : 193.169.0.102 (host ip) ros2 ip : 193.169.0.100 (udp receiver ip) udp port 2112
I had followed the documentation on github from sick:
https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan_xd/blob/develop/USAGE.md
I m not able to launch both the scanners simultaneously. I get the following  error :
ERROR UdpReceiverSocketImpl::Init(:2115): can't bind socket, error: 98 (Address already in use)
I had tried by changing the udp port on the scanner to 4112, but still it tries to bind to the port 2115 & and if another scanner is already connected, gives me the same error.
Regarding the package, i had installed the prebuilt binaries for Humble using the following:
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-sick-scan-xd
Does anyone has sucess in using 2 laser scanners from sick picoscan 150 simultaneously?
Best Regards,
Ravi
